# Software for Windows for organization of ideas

Tags: windows, project-management, knowledge-organization

For organizational purposes, I would like to list my projects and break them into smaller steps, small tasks that can be completed.

I need something like Trello, for Windows, preferably open-source.

Comment: Please be more specific, there are so many task management apps out there. Can it be web based? What about remember the milk for example?

Answer (score 1):

You could use an open source alternative to Trello, still web based: [Wekan](https://wekan.github.io).

Answer (score 0):

How about [ToDoList](http://abstractspoon.weebly.com/)?

- you can create a project with as many sub tasks as you want,
- you can tick off the steps once you complete them,
- runs on Windows,
- is [free and open source](http://abstractspoon.com/wiki/doku.php?id=free-open-source-software).

This is what it looks like:
[image]

It might work for you, so maybe worth a try. But if you could add some specific requirements, as the commentator above suggested, others could suggest better options.

Comment: This is impressive. But I was thinking about something similar to Personal Brain. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pPGaS6UD4gs&t=1s

Comment: Ok, I'll keep an eye out, if I find something similar, I'll post it here.

Comment: So, from what I've seen in the video, you are looking primarily for a mind-mapping tool?

Answer (score 0):

[Eylean Board](http://www.eylean.com) could be a good fit. Just like Trello it is an intuitive project board, where projects can be broken down into steps and tasks. You can then complete the tasks and add relevant information to visualize your current status and progress.

You can use it either with a team or alone and modify the board to your liking. It is not an open source solution though.

[image: Eylean Task Board]